# How to get to a node in a namespaced xml file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to get a node out of an XML file and having a hell of a time.  XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>26.0</apiVersion>
    <label>aaaWsPage2</label>
    <description></description>
    <rffolder>Robert Test</rffolder>
</ApexPage>
```

I tried the following code:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:\test.xml");

var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("ns1", @"http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata");

XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

string query = @"/ns1:ApexClass/ns1:rffolder";
var xmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode(query);
if (xmlNode != null)
   Console.WriteLine(xmlNode.InnerXml);
```

`xmlNode` is always null or I get an exception on `.SelectSingleNode`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Any reason you are not using Linq to XML? the syntax is much easier to use.

Comment: @Jay Care to show me an example?  I've never used Linq with XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always find Linq To Xml easier to use

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(fname);
XNamespace ns = "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata";

var folder = xDoc.Root.Element(ns + "rffolder").Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

can you please try this?

```
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(@"//ns1:ApexClass/ns1:rffolder) as XmlElement;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LinqToXml

```
 var node = XElement.Load(@"C:\Test.xml")
                    .Element(XName.Get("rffolder","http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Linq2Xml:

first of all, in the XML the root is called ApexPage, not ApexClass, and you forgot to pass the XmlNamespaceManager to the SelectSingleNode.

So:

```
string query = @"/ns1:ApexPage/ns1:rffolder";
var xmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode(query, mgr);
```

Should work as well

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query string to:

```
string query = "//ns1:ApexClass/ns1:rffolder";
```